# primefaces treeTable resizableColumns

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.2 .
when I chnage TreeTable style to RTL dir (with css code) :

```
    .ui-treetable .ui-treetable-toggler {
    background-image: url("/WebInputQuery/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_616161_256x240.png.faces?ln=primefaces-aristo");
    background-position-y:-192px;
    background-position-x:-16px;   // + icon
}

.ui-treetable .ui-icon-triangle-1-e
 {
    background-image: url("/WebInputQuery/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_616161_256x240.png.faces?ln=primefaces-aristo");
    background-position-y:-192px;
    background-position-x:0px;  // - icon

}


.ui-treetable TABLE{

    direction: rtl;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.ui-treetable .ui-treetable-toggler{
    float:right;
}


.ui-treetable .ui-treetable-indent {
    float:right;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

the resize option stop working.
I am setting treeTable attributes :

```
resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true"
```

but it doesn't re-size .
how can I fix it ?

Comment: The best way (only way I think), is to do try to find out why it fails ('stops working' is from an enduser point of view, try to find the technical cause) and then download the source and create a patch... sorry

Comment: I tried to find the cause that make it work in LTR but not in RTL mode without any luck. I check this on same computer . any ideas what can cause it ?