# primefaces 5.2 TreeTable direction RTL

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.2 , when I change the treeTable style to  :

```
.ui-treetable TABLE{
direction: rtl;
```

}

the re-size option work wrong , it is appended to the right side of the column and it changes the wrong column width.

how can i fix it?

(I previously posted in: [primefaces treeTable resizableColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592631/primefaces-treetable-resizablecolumns) .. but I handel to reduce the couse of the problem to this)

thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [primefaces treeTable resizableColumns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592631/primefaces-treetable-resizablecolumns)

Comment: Please stick to your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592631/primefaces-treetable-resizablecolumns